# Cant Access Json Output

Tags: javascript, php, json

PHP Code:

```
$contents = '';
$dataarray = file('/location/'.$_GET['playlist'].''); //Push file data into array
$finallist = '';

//Grab Track Info

foreach ($dataarray as $line_num => $line) //Loop Through Data
{
    $line = str_replace("\n", "", $line); //Replace new line on string

    $contents = functionCommand($con, 'uinfo '.$line); //Returns Json for that single track
    if (stripos($contents, '"error":"invalid argument (should be a Spotify URI)"') == FALSE && stripos($contents, '"error": "invalid command"') == FALSE) //If we found tracks
    {
        $finallist .= $contents;
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Fail";
    }
}
$array = explode("\n", $finallist);
array_pop($array);
echo json_encode($array);
```

JAVASCRIPT:

I am trying to access my json response.
I used the built in php function to turn my array into a json output with `json_encode($array)`.

My returned json output:

```
["{\"type\":\"track\",\"artist\":\"Jax Jones, Raye\",\"title\":\"You Don't Know Me\",\"album\":\"You Don't Know Me\",\"duration\":214000,\"offset\":0,\"available\":true,\"popularity\":88}","{\"type\":\"track\",\"artist\":\"MK, Becky Hill\",\"title\":\"Piece of Me\",\"album\":\"Piece of Me\",\"duration\":189000,\"offset\":0,\"available\":true,\"popularity\":65}","{\"type\":\"track\",\"artist\":\"Wankelmut, Emma Louise\",\"title\":\"My Head Is A Jungle - MK Remix \/ Radio Edit\",\"album\":\"My Head Is A Jungle (MK Remix \/ Radio Edit)\",\"duration\":205000,\"offset\":0,\"available\":true,\"popularity\":62}"]
```

I then use `JSON.parse()` to parse the data. The returned output for that is:

```
Array [ "{"type":"track","artist":"Jax Jones…", "{"type":"track","artist":"MK, Becky…", "{"type":"track","artist":"Wankelmut…" ]
```

I am trying to access from a few ways such as:

```
responsedata = JSON.parse(data); //Parse the data
console.log(responsedata.artist[0]); //undefined
console.log(responsedata[0].artist); //undefined
```

EDIT (Full code)

```
$.ajax({
    url : '/db/',
    cache: false,
    data: {cmd: 'viewspotplaylist',playlist: 'Williams Mix'}
}).done(function(data) 
{
    //console.log(data);
    //Something here to make code work.
    //data returns that weird array
});
```

If i `console.log(data)` I get a response of:

```
["{\"type\":\"track\",\"artist\":\"Jax Jones, Raye\",\"title\":\"You Don't Know Me\",\"album\":\"You Don't Know Me\",\"duration\":214000,\"offset\":0,\"available\":true,\"popularity\":88}","{\"type\":\"track\",\"artist\":\"MK, Becky Hill\",\"title\":\"Piece of Me\",\"album\":\"Piece of Me\",\"duration\":189000,\"offset\":0,\"available\":true,\"popularity\":65}","{\"type\":\"track\",\"artist\":\"Wankelmut, Emma Louise\",\"title\":\"My Head Is A Jungle - MK Remix \/ Radio Edit\",\"album\":\"My Head Is A Jungle (MK Remix \/ Radio Edit)\",\"duration\":205000,\"offset\":0,\"available\":true,\"popularity\":62}"]
```

Comment: Something is fishy with your quotation marks. Give your input data a look again :)

Comment: console.log(responsedata.artist) directly access the property

Comment: @tire0011 I receive `undefined` when i also do that! :/

Comment: What are the actual contents of `data` (before the the parse)?

Comment: The contents of Data is what i have listed above. Classed as `My returned json output:`

Comment: Check my answer and try it in your console like that.

Comment: var responsedata = JSON.parse(data);  add the var

Comment: He is probably sending a array o json encoded objects to the client Kumar answer covers that and I have a feeling it is the correct one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First i would like to thank everyone for their help and efforts put into getting me going!

I decided to go back into the PHP side of things and recode it to only echo out the variable $finallist and not to put it into an array and then json encode it! Then on the Javascript side of things i created an array from the data and then used some information provided above to get me going.

Final product:

```
$.ajax({
    url : '/db/',
    cache: false,
    data: {cmd: 'viewspotplaylist',playlist: 'Williams Mix'}
}).done(function(data) 
{
    var dataarray = [];
    dataarray = data.split("\n");
    dataarray.pop();
    console.log(dataarray);
    var responsedata = JSON.parse("[" + dataarray.join(",") + "]"); //Parse the data
    console.log(responsedata[0].artist); //Displays
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your input data is an array of strings, you should need to build your full string.

This code will help:

```
responsedata = JSON.parse("[" + data.join(",") + "]");
```

Comment: I receive: `data.join is not a function` in console. Code doesnt run!

Comment: is your data rray declared like that?: var data = ["{\"type\":\"track\",\"artist\":\"Jax Jones, Raye\",\"title\":\"You Don't Know Me\",\"album\":\"You Don't Know.......]

Comment: The data is from a ajax request. The ajax calls my php which then creates and then reforms my array into json.

Comment: try to put a debugger; action to see in the console what is the structure of data variable, that will be the key,

Comment: join method will be only available if data is an array. If data is an object, it may contains an internal array, probably data.data or similar

Comment: How can i convert to a real array? If you check my php code. Thats how i echo the output to java. (not sure how code php you have though!)

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON in:

```
 Array [ "{"type":"track","artist":"Jax Jones…", 
"{"type":"track","artist":"MK, Becky…", 
"{"type":"track","artist":"Wankelmut…"
```

Seems to be **malformed**. There shouldn't have a quotation mark as `"{"type":`

You must parse your JSON differently.
Declare in your console:

```
var data = ["{\"type\":\"track\",\"artist\":\"Jax Jones, Raye\",\"title\":\"You Don't Know Me\",\"album\":\"You Don't Know Me\",\"duration\":214000,\"offset\":0,\"available\":true,\"popularity\":88}","{\"type\":\"track\",\"artist\":\"MK, Becky Hill\",\"title\":\"Piece of Me\",\"album\":\"Piece of Me\",\"duration\":189000,\"offset\":0,\"available\":true,\"popularity\":65}","{\"type\":\"track\",\"artist\":\"Wankelmut, Emma Louise\",\"title\":\"My Head Is A Jungle - MK Remix \/ Radio Edit\",\"album\":\"My Head Is A Jungle (MK Remix \/ Radio Edit)\",\"duration\":205000,\"offset\":0,\"available\":true,\"popularity\":62}"]
```

then parse your data like this:

```
var responsedata = JSON.parse("[" + data.join(",") + "]");
```

Then you can use responsedata[i], where i is an index value to access each data element.

E.g.

```
console.log(responsedata[0].artist);
```

### Edit

```
 $.ajax({
        url : '/db/',
        cache: false,
        data: {cmd: 'viewspotplaylist',playlist: 'Williams Mix'}
    }).done(function(data) 
        {
            //console.log(data);

        // To convert data to an array, you can do:

        var dataArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(data);
        var responsedata = JSON.parse("[" + dataArray.join(",") + "]");
        console.log(responsedata[0].artist); // This does not work?
    });
```

Comment: I receive `data.join is not a function` like said above in José Quinto Zamora Answer!:)

Comment: If you try this in developer tools it works. Could you be kind as to point out the variable name of the data you get back? What argument do you send to JSON.parse(/*Argument??*/)? Whatever your JSON argument is there, then you can apply:

responsedata = JSON.parse("[" + argumentName.join(",") + "]");

Comment: My argument is data. I will post full ajax code above!

Comment: So data = ["{\"type\":\"track\",\"artist\":\"Jax Jones, Raye\",\"title\":\"You Don't Know Me\",\"album\":\"You Don't Know Me\",\"duration\":214000,\"offset\":0,\"available\":true,\"popularity\":88}"........]
??

Comment: I updated my Question. If i console.log(data). I receive: `["{\"type\":\"track\",\"artist\":\"Jax Jones, Raye\",\"title\":\"You Don't Know Me\",\"album\":..`

Comment: I receive: `TypeError: data.join is not a function[Learn More]` error in console log

Comment: With the "var" before "responsedata" as well?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138549/discussion-between-irishwill200-and-santiago-varela).

Answer (score 1):

Check this script

```js
var data = ["{\"type\":\"track\",\"artist\":\"Jax Jones, Raye\",\"title\":\"You Dont Know Me\",\"album\":\"You Dont Know Me\",\"duration\":214000,\"offset\":0,\"available\":true,\"popularity\":88}", "{\"type\":\"track\",\"artist\":\"MK, Becky Hill\",\"title\":\"Piece of Me\",\"album\":\"Piece of Me\",\"duration\":189000,\"offset\":0,\"available\":true,\"popularity\":65}", "{\"type\":\"track\",\"artist\":\"Wankelmut, Emma Louise\",\"title\":\"My Head Is A Jungle - MK Remix \/ Radio Edit\",\"album\":\"My Head Is A Jungle (MK Remix \/ Radio Edit)\",\"duration\":205000,\"offset\":0,\"available\":true,\"popularity\":62}"];
    if (typeof data != 'object')
        data = JSON.parse(data);
    var jsonArray = [];
    $.each(data, function (index, item) {
        jsonArray.push(JSON.parse(item));
    });
    console.log(jsonArray[0].artist);
```

```html
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This works if i exactly copy into my code. But when i change `jsonTextArray` to data i receive `TypeError: invalid 'in' operand a`

Comment: I still receive the error: `TypeError: invalid 'in' operand a`

Comment: Again, I have updated the code added JSON.parse. Please try it.